# Spring mvc + Security css and js in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My jsp pages don't open a css and js files. I tried some solutions which I found here, like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./pages//style/style.css">
 <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="style/style.css" />" />
```

but nothing help.

[image: structure]

My securityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                 .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                 .antMatchers("/basket/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                  .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                 .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

CSS file can not be opened in the presence of Spring security and also in pure Spring MVC.  In  debug log:

```
/style/style.css at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain ....
/style/style.css at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain
 Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /style/style.css; Attributes: [permitAll]
```

https://github.com/Panwo/ProjV2.git

Edit:

```
@Configuration
public class NewConfigure extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Should I just declare this class or inject it anywhere, maybe in 
**SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer**?

**Edit 2**
[image]

Сan be a problem in the settings ? When I remove web module from war I get 404.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your edits. Yes you must specify it in your _Initializer_ class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have not specified static resource mapping. so your `dispatcher` is looking for mapping for the static resources. Since you are using Java Based configuration add a configuration class extending from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`
and override the following method:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Now you must refer in your jsp :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style/styles.css">
```

**EDIT:** (In response to your updated question)

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{NewConfigure.class}; // Here is your updated config
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but nothing changed. I updated question, maybe you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore security for the resources like CSS and Javascripts files by overriding `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)`

In your `SecurityConfig.java` override the above method as follows.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/style/**");
}
```

Comment: doesn't help .                                                                                                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/style/styles.css">

   <link href="<c:url value="style/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">